# Crystals, symmetries in mixture

Tags: symmetry, physical-chemistry, crystals, ice, freezing

What would happen to the crystal structure of ice, if i freeze salt water?

What changes in symmetry can i expect? I do not know the terminology for this stuff...but in what 'subclass' or 'subfamily', whatever one calls it, would the new crystal end up in?

Originally i was wondering what happens if i mix sugar and salt in water, and wait for it to dry out. What type of crystals would i expect? Can they even mix? But the freezing salt water example is more intuitive.

I accept answers to either question : )

Comment: Generally you get phase separation, with the water ice incorporating varying amounts of salt in it, up to the solubility limit. The crystal structure remains the same, with some distortions (but then just solidifying a pure solid often ends up with distortions as well - growing high quality crystals is hard).

Comment: Hmm, alright, thank you.